# Radius of convergence and the existence of antiderivative

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, complex-integration, laurent-series

I think I have some misunderstandings regarding some basic concepts.
First, the question I'm dealing with is the following:

> Let $f$ be analytic in $\{z ;|z|>1 \}$, and $\int_{|z|=2}f(z)dz=0$. Show that $f$ has a primitive in $\{z ;|z|>1 \}$

I know that if $f$ is analytic on this domain, then it has a Laurent expansion which is integrable term-by-term  (where $|z| > 1$) hence a primitive exists. What do I need the other condition $\int_{|z|=2}f(z)dz=0$ for?

Comment: By your reasoning, $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$ has a primitive on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Do you think $1/z$ has a primitive in that region?

Comment: @zhw, I might be mistaken, but was that question meant for me?

Comment: no, otherwise I would have written @SoumyaSinha.

Comment: Oh, sorry to bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Claim}$: Suppose $f$ is analytic in a domain $\Omega$. Then, $f$ has a primitive in $\Omega$ iff $\int\limits_{\gamma}{}f=0$ for every simple closed curve $\gamma \in \Omega$.

In your case, every simple closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega=\{z:|z|>1\}$ is homotopic to either a contractible loop or a loop around $0$, which we can assume to be the circle $|z|=2$. Now, check that the claim holds.

Comment: You don't need to know all that to answer the question.

Comment: @zhw, agreed. But I just wrote the first thing that popped in my head. If the OP doesn't know all this, then I'll be happy to try other methods.

Comment: The elaboration was actually very helpful. Thanks! @SoumyaSinha